# How should I obtain haproxy's detailed http logs when using ssl?

Tags: logging, ssl, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy's `option httplog` logs extensively.  We're about to move to ssl frontends though, which causes me to lose that info.  Is there a recommended way to continue to get this logging detail?

It seems like I could either:

- use stunnel in front of haproxy to decrypt the traffic
- aggregate the logs from the tomcats instead

Is there a better or recommended way?  I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminate SSL with `nginx` on port 443, and do a reverse proxy to `haproxy` on port 80.

All logs will then be available via `option httplog`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's the direction it looks like we'll head.

Answer (score 1):

```
frontend https-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt  /etc/ssl/private/xxx.com.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend finance_koala_server_https
    option httplog
```

key point config:

option httplog  in https-in

see log:

Jan 14 12:48:57 localhost haproxy[39918]: 117.136.40.129:14853 [14/Jan/2015:12:48:57.127] https-in~ xx_server_https/xxx_node_8002 170/0/0/3/173 200 739 - - --NN 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /xxx/xxx HTTP/1.1"